# I can't figure out a destructor for this 2D ptr array. Need suggestions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, destructor

I've been thinking hard for a destructor of 2D pointer array. Any suggestions would be of great help. 
The following is the structure of my array where **x = int's**  AND * = pointers

```
+---+---+---+
| * | * | * |
+-|-+-|-+-|-+
  |   |   V
  |   | +---+---+---+
  |   | | x | x | x |
  |   | +---+---+---+
  |   V
  | +---+---+---+
  | | x | x | x |
  | +---+---+---+
  V
+---+---+---+
| x | x | x |
+---+---+---+
```

Here is the code for my constructor:

```
matrix(int x, int y)
{
    m = x;
    n = y;
    p = new(int *[m]);      

    for(i=0 ; i<m ; i++)    
        p[i] = new(int[n]);
}
```

Comment: You want to `delete[] array[i]` first in a loop, then `delete[] array` itself.

Comment: You want to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]` because otherwise your code is inherently exception-unsafe and requires you to implement the rule of five yourself instead of taking advantage of the rule of zero.

Comment: sorry but This was a class assignment, and it was necessary to just use constructors and destructor. Exceptions or vectors were not the topic of focus !

Comment: Unless there is a pressing need for variant row-widths within your matrix, you can do this with a single allocation and an overloaded `int * operator [](int n)`, just fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~matrix()
{                               
    for(i=0 ; i<m ; i++)    
        delete[] p[i];
    delete[] p;
}
```